# Entity Framework 4 load Record by ID

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

So I am looking at creating a generic Interface to interact with my DataStorage of my objects one that I can swap out to use EF4 or SubSonic or NHibernate or some NoSQL option.

So I have an ERD and every table has an auto incrementing int column "TableNameID" that is the primary key I am trying to figure out how to get a single record from the DB using the primary key in a Generic method

```
public T GetSingle<T>(int primaryKey) where T : class
```

How do you do this using EF4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this via the generic [ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383062(v=VS.100).aspx).

E.g., something like:

```
public T GetSingle<T>(int primaryKey) where T : class
{
    var q = Context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where("it.TableNameID = @tableNameId");
    q.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("tableNameId", primaryKey));
    return q.Single();
}
```

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear if the Table's name is Users the  Primary Key is UsersID.  I think this is a start but I guess it would work best if I can find the name of the Primary Key somehow via EF4

Comment: This looks like it is the best answer I can find along with using reflection to find the class name and have the class name the same as the table name and all IDs follow a standard.

Comment: You don't need reflection to get the class name. `typeof(T).Name` will do, and doesn't require `System.Reflection`

Comment: I asked another related question.  And posted the answer there which works better than the one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958921/entity-framework-4-how-to-find-the-primary-key

Comment: You said you were trying to avoid reflection? Changed your mind on that?