# Entity Framework 4: How to find the primary key?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, primary-key

I am trying to create a generic method using EF4 to find the primary key of an object.

example

```
public string GetPrimaryKey<T>()
{
    ...
}
```

To give more info I am working off of the Tekpub StarterKit and below is the class I am trying to get up and running

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.ELinq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using Web.Infrastructure.Storage.EF4;

namespace Web.Infrastructure.Storage {
public class EFSession:ISession {
    PuzzleEntities _db;//This is an ObjectContext
    public EFSession() {
        _db = new PuzzleEntities();
    }

    public void CommitChanges() {
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the table provided by the type T and returns for querying
    /// </summary>
    private ObjectSet<T> GetObjectSet<T>() where T:class {
        return _db.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    private T GetByPrimaryKey<T>() where T: class
    {
        .....
    }

    public void Delete<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T: class{

        foreach (T item in All<T>().Where(expression))
        {
            GetObjectSet<T>().DeleteObject(item);
        }
    }

    public void Delete<T>(T item) where T : class {
        GetObjectSet<T>().DeleteObject(item);
    }

    public void DeleteAll<T>() where T : class {
        foreach(T item in All<T>())
        {
            GetObjectSet<T>().DeleteObject(item);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _db.Dispose();
    }

    public T Single<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T:class {
        return GetObjectSet<T>().SingleOrDefault(expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class {
        return GetObjectSet<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public void Add<T>(T item) where T : class {
        GetObjectSet<T>().AddObject(item);
    }
    public void Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            GetObjectSet<T>().AddObject(item);
        }
    }
    public void Update<T>(T item) where T : class {
        //nothing needed here
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So I was finally able to find out how to get this to work.  I wish I hadn't lost the link to the blog I read last night as I didn't write the code.

```
public T GetByPrimaryKey<T>(int id) where T : class
{
    return (T)_db.GetObjectByKey(new EntityKey(_db.DefaultContainerName + "." + this.GetEntityName<T>(), GetPrimaryKeyInfo<T>().Name, id));
}

string GetEntityName<T>()
{
    string name = typeof(T).Name;
    if (name.ToLower() == "person")
        return "People";
    else if (name.Substring(name.Length - 1, 1).ToLower() == "y")
        return name.Remove(name.Length - 1, 1) + "ies";
    else if (name.Substring(name.Length - 1, 1).ToLower() == "s")
        return name + "es";
    else
        return name + "s";
}

private PropertyInfo GetPrimaryKeyInfo<T>()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pI in properties)
    {
        System.Object[] attributes = pI.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        foreach (object attribute in attributes)
        {
            if (attribute is EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)
            {
                if ((attribute as EdmScalarPropertyAttribute).EntityKeyProperty == true)
                    return pI;
            }
            else if (attribute is ColumnAttribute)
            {

                if ((attribute as ColumnAttribute).IsPrimaryKey == true)
                    return pI;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I hope this helps someone else.  All I can say is that it should be a little clearer on how to do this.

Comment: I'm guessing it was from: http://www.guerrillasyntax.com/index.php/2010/04/24/linq-to-entity-generic-repository/

Comment: Technically not valid, since this will return incorrect results if there is a composite primary key.

Comment: I doubt it would work if you're establishing your FKs via the fluent api either.

Answer (score 16):

There is a property on each EF4 entity called `EntityKey` which contains an array of `EntityKeyValues` (array is there in case of compound key).

You could reference this directly on your entity instance or create a generic helper method that does this under the covers. If I can test-drive some sample code, I'll post it up here.

*Edit*: The EntityKeyValue is a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` where the `key` is the primary key field of the entity and the `value` is the associated value.

E.g., I have an entity called `Company` whose primary key is the field `Symbol`.

```
var firstCompany = (from c in context.Companies select c).FirstOrDefault();
var kvp = firstCompany.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0];
// kvp shows {[Symbol, FOO]}
```

In my sandbox, I noticed this property was `null` when I created the entity in code. But once I read the entity from the database, it was correctly populated. So, it appears that the EF4 concept of a primary key only comes in to play once it hits the database. Although, you are free to set it explicitly ahead of time, if you wish.

Comment: You can also try context.Companies.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers

Comment: how come I don't have that property?

Comment: In case anyone is coming to this late... EntityKey only exists on objects that inherit from EntityObject; the only ones that do that are model-first stuff.

Answer (score 6):

I assume many people stop by this post just by looking "Entity framework how to find the primary key?" regardless EF version (like me). So I wanted to mentioned that with EF 6.1, you can also create an extension methods to get the primary key. 
Following is the example and works perfectly fine.

**PS: I am not 100% sure, if that would work with composite and compound keys tho.**

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;

namespace System.Data.Entity
{
    public static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        public static string[] GetKeyNames<TEntity>(this DbContext context)
            where TEntity : class
        {
            return context.GetKeyNames(typeof(TEntity));
        }

        public static string[] GetKeyNames(this DbContext context, Type entityType)
        {
            var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

            // Get the mapping between CLR types and metadata OSpace
            var objectItemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));

            // Get metadata for given CLR type
            var entityMetadata = metadata
                    .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
                    .Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == entityType);

            return entityMetadata.KeyProperties.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

[Original Source](https://romiller.com/2014/10/07/ef6-1-getting-key-properties-for-an-entity/)

Comment: This worked for me for an entity with a composite key

Answer (score 1):

this seems needlessly long?
I have had the same need, and using the suggestions above (by SethO and denis_n), i am using:

```
        //get the primary key field name and location for the table
        var primaryFieldName = entry.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers[0].Name ;
        int primaryFieldLocation = entry.CurrentValues.GetOrdinal(primaryFieldName);
        //gets the value pair for the primary key (returns field name + value)
        var primaryField = entry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[primaryFieldLocation];
        String primaryFieldValue = primaryField.Value.ToString();
```

Hope this helps anyone who is interested

Comment: Is "entry" value column name?

Comment: @rana you are assuming only one column is a primary key

Comment: What is the data type of entry? I could not understand what is it. Can you provide an example?