# EF 4.1 How to get the first key of an entity - composite

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a Class where I have 2 Keys (Composite Keys), then I have my audit log function where I used to get the primary key of an entity like this:

```
string keyName = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Count() > 0).Name;
```

The problem is that one of the models im trying to save have a composite key:

```
 [Key,Column("paymentdetailid", TypeName = "int", Order=0)]
    public Int32 PaymentDetailId { get; set; }

    [Key,Column("chargedetailid", TypeName = "int", Order=1)]
    public Int32 ChargeDetailId { get; set; }
```

Im getting the following error when trying to get the keyName:

```
Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

Any clue on how to solve this? I just want to get the first key.

Thanks,

**SOLUTION**

The solution is this one:

var keyNames = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Count() > 0).ToList();

string keyName = keyNames[0].Name;

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be using "Single" if you want more then one result?

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958921/entity-framework-4-how-to-find-the-primary-key

Comment: You are right. The issue was "Single". Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace `Single` by `First` to get the first property with a key attribute:

```
string keyName = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().First(
    p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Any()).Name;
```

Also `Any()` is a bit cleaner than `Count() > 0` as it just says "check if the property *has* a key attribute". Or use `FirstOrDefault` if you want to catch the case that the type has no key attribute at all and throw an appropriate exception (`FirstOrDefault` will return `null` then whereas `First` will throw a "Sequence contains no element" exception):

```
var property = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(
    p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Any());

if (property == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
        "Entity {0} has no [Key] attribute.", dbEntry.Entity.GetType().Name));

string keyName = property.Name;
```