# How to Find Identity column from class of entity frame work using C# code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to find identity column from class property.(using entity frame and c# code).

i.e 
I have a class that created from database using Entity framework that contains one identity column.How we can check that which property is identity column?

I am showing form dynamically based on table property but I don't want show the identity property to the user because it is auto increment.

Comment: which approach you are using code first or database first, for code first approach one with annotation  [Key] is used for primary key.

Comment: I am using database first

Comment: I hope this help: [How to find the primary key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958921/entity-framework-4-how-to-find-%20the-primary-key)

Comment: probably posting your table schema and genrated model might help here, also please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj206878.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 if it helps