# Get record from DB using reflection and generic type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to retrieve an instance from DB. I have created a db model using EF. I can do it the static way:

```
var tempRecord= db.Table1.First(a => a.column1 ==  columnValue);
```

But how to do this if the current table's class changes and sometimes it's Table1 and sometimes Table2?
I tried something like this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
Type entityType = Type.GetType(currentTable);
var tempRecord2 = db.entityType.First(a => a.column1 == columnValue);
```

EDIT: currentTable is a string

There is 5 tables and each table needs different columns to be checked out. So I would have list of columns to be checked for each table

Comment: You can use `db.currentTable.First(a => a.column1 == columnValue)`. Are you tried this?

Comment: currentTable is a string

Comment: Is it only two tables or potentially more? If only two tables, just query them both and check if the entities are null :-)

Comment: There is 5 tables and each table needs different columns to be checked out. So I would have list of columns to be checked for each table.

Comment: Alright, could you insert a screenshot of your tables and their relations? There might be room for structural improvements :-)

Comment: do the columns on the different tables have the same name? and are they consistent?

Comment: That I can't do sadly. And how would it help? Let's assume I have one table and we don't know its type. That is all I need but I searched and searched and can't find a solution other than doing switch case and writing everthing static-like.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a generic method with a `where T : YourEntityTypeClass`? the issue is that every object would need to have a `column1` column..

Comment: Some are the same some are not. The relations are described in the mapping table from which I can retrieve needed column names.

Comment: @Passer7by it could help because when you need to query multiple tables for the exact same value, it could mean that the db design could be optimised. Not trying to be rude at all here :-) Either do multiple queries and check for null values or, as fhcimolin suggested, make your method generic.

Comment: @BoMortensen I know you are not rude. Sorry if I came as defensive. Is there another aproach? Because for each table I will have different columns to check to get that specific record.

Comment: @Passer7by it's all good :-) Hmmn.. you'd have to do quite a bit of reflection magic to check for difference columns for each of the tables. First check if the generic entity has a property of the value you need to check for and then check the value itself. Might be better to just query the database for all the tables needed and then perform your checkups with the in-memory result then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest having a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958921/entity-framework-4-how-to-find-the-primary-key) answer, should it inspire you.

In it, the code relies on generic functions, passing a LINQ `Func<>` to delegate the `First()` (or in his case, the `SingleOrDefault()`) so it can execute the same method for any ObjectSet (or table) that is sent to the method, just like down below:

```
 public T Single<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T:class {
        return GetObjectSet<T>().SingleOrDefault(expression);
    }
```

So far so good. But this way, your columns would have to be all named `column1`. But a suggestion would be to retrieve the primary key, which is also explained further in the linked answer.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
    Type entityType = Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.Models.City");
    var result = ((IQueryable<object>)db.Set(entityType)).FirstOrDefault();
```

except for the columns checking.
One possible solution for adding the columns checking is to use a Parent class that contains all the fields that are participated in all tables filtering and change the second line to this:

```
var result = ((IQueryable<ParentClass>)db.Set(entity)).First(a => a.column1 == columnValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "column1" is a common property, you could use this method:

```
        Type type = Type.GetType(currentTable);
        IEnumerable a = db.Database.SqlQuery(type, "SELECT * FROM " + name + " WHERE column1 = " + "x");
```

Then, depending on the database modify the query and get the first row, or cast at runtime and use First().

Answer (score 1):

If the case is that you **only** have five tables with the same column and you need to query the database for each of these tables for that column and then *afterwards* perform checks against the result on *different* columns, then I think I'd go for a KISS solution rather than using reflection.

Given this example tables:

```
Table1
    ColumnA, Table1ColumnB, Table1ColumnC

Table2
    ColumnA, Table2ColumnB, Table2ColumnC

Table3
    ColumnA, Table3ColumnB, Table3ColumnC
```

And if no more tables are to be added, I'd query them like this:

```
using(var ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    Table1 tbl1 = ctx.Table1s.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnA == "myvalue");
    Table2 tbl2 = ctx.Table2s.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnA == "myvalue");
    Table3 tbl3 = ctx.Table3s.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ColumnA == "myvalue");

    // Perform null checks and other checks against different columns here
}
```

In short: don't overthink it :-)